# printing variable in class in javascript

Tags: javascript

guys i have that simple code ... but it print undeifned but i dont know why

```js
function myMove() {  
  this.pos = 0;
  this.right = function() {
  fun();
  }
  function fun(){
   this.pos++;
  }
 
}

var move = new myMove();
alert(move.right());
```

any help ???

Comment: `right` doesn't return anything. What are you expecting it to print?

Comment: @Carcigenicate want it to print "1"

Comment: `this.pos++` -> `return this.pos++`

`fun();` -> `return fun();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value from `fun()` and `this.right`.

```
function myMove() {  
  var pos = 0;
  this.right = function() {
     return fun();
  }
  function fun(){
      return pos++;
  }

}

var move = new myMove();
alert(move.right());
```

Comment: can you explain why ?

Comment: btw it print NAN not "1"

Comment: Oh - pos is not defined because the `this` is not the same for pos and the fun() context. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

you need to use `pos` not `this.pos` while initializing

```js
function myMove() {  
  pos = 0;
  this.right = function() {
  return fun();
  }
  function fun(){
  this.pos++;
     return this.pos;
  }
 
}

var move = new myMove();
alert(move.right());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myMove() {  
  pos = 0;
  this.right = function() {
  return fun();
  }
  function fun(){
     return ++this.pos;
  }
 
}

var move = new myMove();
alert(move.right());
```

In javascript use need to user `return` keyword to return a value from a function
Also
Instead of postfix `pos++` operator you will have to use a prefix operator `++pos`

Difference is that postfix operator will first return a value and the increment it whereas
Prefix operator will first increment the value and then it will process it